what is pMC percent modern carbon?
In material about carbon dating I see a lot of results expressed in pMC.  For example I saw a 14C/C ratio of .12 pMC.  My understanding is that the amount of 14C in carbon is about one trillionth. I've tried a bunch web pages but can't seem to find a clear (to me) answer. What is pMC in general, and what would a ratio of 14C/C expressed in pMC mean?
